# Using Postfix to relay incoming mail to an unreliable mail server

Tags: postfix, email-server

So I have a mail server with the address "mail.tablesandchairs.com" which for reasons out of my control is connected via 4g wireless.

For the most part it works perfectly, until the wireless drops out, sometimes for as much as an hour. The problem is that emails get bounced back when the server is unreachable.

Now I am instructed to setup a relay mail server that all the mail goes via, so that, when the main wireless server is unreachable, the mail can just queue up on the relay until the link is re-established.

I've pretty much got it and have been testing with telnet but I can only send mail from `localhost`, and not from say "bob@blinds.com" who is on a random computer in the internet and is very interested in buying some tables and chairs from "sales@mail.tablesandchars.com".

So to sum up, I need all incoming mail to go via a middle relay server that can queue up mail when the main mail server goes down. Mail needs to come from ANYWHERE but go to "mail.tablesandchars.com" ONLY.

My `main.cf` is as follows:

```
smtp_use_tls = no  
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

relay_recipient_maps =
relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/relaydomains
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks
 reject_unauth_destination

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = mail.relay.com.au
mydomain = relay.com.au
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, main.mail.ip.address

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = .maildir/
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no

relayhost = main.mail.ip.address
```

The relaydomains:

```
mail.tablesandchairs.com OK
tablesandchairs.com OK
```

And the transport:

```
tablesandchairs.com smtp:[tablesandchairs.com]:25
mail.tablesandchairs.com.au smtp:[tablesandchairs.com]:25
```

Comment: Hmm okay, so this question has only been up for 1 hour and somebody has already down voted it for no apparent reason....?

Comment: If your email is really important, don't host it on an unreliable connection. You can spend less than 5 dollares a month on a mail server from a hosting company, probably costs less than the 4g wireless you are using. Not my downvote...

Comment: Look guys, dont get me wrong, if it were up to me then I would. I kinda have my hands tied here....

Comment: Sorry, but the "*management is making me do something I accept is dumb*" excuse doesn't really wash around here.  Part of being a professional is speaking truth unto power.

Comment: you obviously don't have a job / have never worked with clients before then...

Comment: I'm going to use the privacy argument here. A setup like this can be used as a safe way to keep email stored away in a private system away from the Internet that only the "public relay server" has access to, be it via a VPN or some other secure connection.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not need to complicate the configuration**.

One hour connection issue - it's not so much. Every email server will try to send mails from several hours up to several days (more often). And you will receive your emails in any case.

---

I want to know some details about your infrastructure. You can configure one mail server with good internet connection but you still using the old server with the bad connection?

Deploy your main server at place of relay server instead and take profit!

Comment: yes thats right, I have setup a new server with a very good connection, but the current existing server has tons of existing email accounts and has an unreliable connection.